# RxJava combinator for combining maps?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `Map` of tasks like this:

```
Map<Identifier, Observable<Progress>> tasks;
```

I would like to transform this to:

```
Observable<Map<Identifier, Progress>>
```

Where each `Map<Identifier, Progress> element` contains the latest element from each task.

I want the new `Observable` to complete only when *all* tasks have completed, and fail when *any* one of the tasks fails.

Is there a combinator for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform single `Map<Identifier, Observable<Progress>> task` to `<Identifier, Progress>` use:

```
Observable.just(Identifier)
    .flatMap(Observable<Progress> progressObservable, 
        (Identifier, Progress, Pair<Identifier, Progress>) -> {create pair of elements})
```

To combine those tasks together, use [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#combineLatest(java.util.List,%20rx.functions.FuncN)) operator

```
Observable.combineLatest(List<Observable<Pair<Identifier, Progress>>>, 
    (List<Pair<Identifier, Progress>>) -> {merge into `Map`})
```

I hope I get your idea well. OF course, written in pseudocode.

---

An implementation:

```
public static <T, S> Observable<Map<T, S>> zipMaps(final Map<T, Observable<S>> tasks) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(tasks, "tasks is null");
    return Observable.combineLatest(
        tasks.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> Observable.combineLatest(
                Observable.just(entry.getKey()),
                entry.getValue(),
                Pair::with))
            .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList()),
        xs -> Arrays.stream(xs)
            .map(x -> (Pair<T, S>)x)
            .collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(Pair::getValue0, Pair::getValue1)));
}
```

Comment: Seems to work. I added my implementation from your hints.